# how to install Varnish on windows azure?

Tags: azure, varnish

I just 'quick create' a website in windows azure with the simple step below and it's an IIS8.0 based site.
[image]

How to install Varnish in front of this IIS server in windows azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run Varnish on a website which is actually not just standard IIS (see: http://www.slideshare.net/maartenba/windows-azure-web-sites-things-they-dont-teach-kids-in-school-comunity-day-2013).  As others have said you'll need to run a VM to install Varnish.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you must change to Virtual Machine execution model to install varnish cache.